# ubuntu 16.04 lts, send mail using external (hosting provider) dns

Tags: apache2, dns, email

I set Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server as web server (apache-php-mysql and sendmail) with valid public ip-address. Also, I use a hosting provider to redirect www.mydomain.com to my Ubuntu web server.
Web server work fine but when I use php script for sending email, recipients get emails as a spam.

My hostname is
servername.mydomain.com

My hosts is
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
ipaddress servername.mydomain.com servername

Does anyone know what should I do to force Ubuntu server to send proper email?

Comment: You mail server needs to have an FQDN(reverse dns should match your mail address)  so it won't be classified as spam.

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: Contact your ISP to configure a correct reverse domain name

Comment: I already did it, they said to add a spf record. I did it but nothing has changed.